# HOW TO FIX Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Cant get "id" from my form and idk why

Here's pug code:

```
mixin product(data)
  form(action="/cart" method="POST") 
    .product-card
      a(href="/details/" + data.id)= data.name
      input(type='hidden' name='id' value= data.id)
      button(type="submit")= "Add to cart"
```

Here's Router:

```
router.post("/cart",async (req,res)=>{
  const product = await db.ProductTable.findOne({
    where: {id: req.body.id}
  })
  const newprod = await db.CartsTable.create({
    name: product.name,
    price: product.price
  })
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

I have express.urlencoded
Main error is : Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value
P.S. if I do like `where: {id: 7}` it's working

Help me pls :(

I even got a body of request on my chrome and it still not working
[image: Screenshot from Chrome showing form data]

Comment: Show your express configuration code

Comment: where I can find it ?

Comment: ```const expressJson = express.json();
const bodyParser  = express.urlencoded({extended: true});
app.use([expressJson, bodyParser]);``` Add this line of code above your route and confirm if it's working.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh ty bro its working